# ES6 javascript cannot load bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I try to init bootstrap tooltip with ecmascript, but it doesnt work.
Some of my modules work like socket io and notify. But when i try to include bootstrap tooltip i get an error messages that it is undefined.
This is my code

```
import {Profiletimer} from './Profiletimer';
import {Bid} from './Bid';
import $ from 'jquery';
import "bootstrap-notify";
import "bootstrap-tooltip";

import io from "socket.io-client";
import {settings} from "./config";

/**
 * Profile timers
 * @type {Profiletimer}
 */
$( document ).ready(function() {


  console.log($('elem').tooltip()); // gives error

});
```

In the console it gives me this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jquery___default(...)(...).tooltip is not a function
```

Comment: My guess is that Bootstrap expects a global jQuery. Try `window.$ = window.jQuery = $` after importing jQuery and before importing Bootstrap plugins.

Comment: already tried, but no effect

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me and should work for all tooltips included in your Bootstrap HTML

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=modal]' });
});
```